# Is there a correct form of using find?

Tags: powershell, command

I am trying to delete everything except **init**.py, using this command in powershell(windows 10 and python django version- 2.2.7):

> find . -path "*/blog/migrations/*.py" -not -name "**init**.py" -delete

**Tree of this project**(attaching image)

[image]

**If i run the command i am getting this error:

> FIND: Parameter format not correct

What to do? Thank you in advance. I am new to python django.**

Comment: That image is an image of plain text. It would have been trivial to paste it as text. Please take a look at this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: @zvone i know but the problem is not on this, if i had pasted it, it would have had another form

Comment: the `FIND.exe` command is NOT powershell. also, from what i can tell, the `CMD.exe` version of `Find.exe` does not support the options you show in your post. what OS and what version of `Find.exe` are you using?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i am using windows, not os and not find.exe

Comment: The syntax you're using is that of a _Unix_ `find` utility, whereas the error message implies that the  _Windows_ `find.exe` utility was called.

Comment: @NickDruta - your image shows powershell. the error indicates that you were running `Find.exe` from windows. **_the options you used are NOT valid for the windows `Find.exe` util_**. ///// the `what OS` question referred to `Operating System`, not to MacOS` - so what windows OS are you running? do you have any non-standard `find` utility installed - perhaps the `Windows System for Linux`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i resolved it, i made this process manually

Comment: @NickDruta - that is one way to get around providing the required info to get useful help ... [*frown*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i mentioned it in my question it's windows 10.

Comment: @NickDruta - ah! i managed to miss that part ... sorry for that - but not for telling you that your answers have been FAR less than helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will delete all files that aren't named "init.py". Make sure to run this at the root of the folder you would like to delete items from.

```
Get-Childitem -File -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Name -ne "init.py"} | Remove-Item -WhatIf
```

To test, leave the `-WhatIf` switch. If it displays the files you would like to remove, run again without the `-WhatIf` switch.

Comment: Didn't worked i still have the same files @infosecb

Comment: Nice, though using `-Exclude init.py` with `Get-ChildItem` is both simpler and faster. @NickDruta, this should work, but you'll have to pass the target path to `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: @NickDruta, you may notice the `-WhatIf` parameter applied to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet. That only displays what would happen if you ran it, and does not actually take action. Remove the `-WhatIf` and it should delete the files. Also, what mklement0 said about `-exclude init.py` being faster. Always filter at the `Get-ChildItem` level if possible.